# How can I add a property set value "intern" automatically to each new repository on artifactory 7.x?

Tags: properties, set, artifactory

I created the property set confidentiality level in Actifactory 7 instance. My property ser contains all values (""öffentlich,"intern" and "vertraulich") described as a selection list.

I assigned the value level "intern" as default manually to my old repositories.But now I want to automate this property set with "intern" so that the "intern" property set is automatically added to each new repository.I readed the Jfrog documentation about property set and found nothing there.

But I'd rather add the "intern" property for the new repositories automatically in the future.
I added some pictures to show you ,what I already did.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Tree view of Artifacts > navigate to your repository > Open Properties Tab > Select/add properties > Check mark Recursive. (When checked, the property will be added to the selected folder and to all of the artifacts, folders and sub-folders under the current selection). Attached the image.

[image]

Comment: Recursive it just for this generic-local repo and his folder . I already try it .

Comment: Let me re-iterate it. Recrsive is possible on a single repository where the properties will be applied to all the existing artifacts and for new uploads as well.

Automation of setting the properties to the repositories which will be created in future is not possible.

Comment: Adding new artifacts does not get the property.

Comment: Did you add the property and mark it as recursive? In that case, when you add a new artifact, it should get the property for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateRepository) to create a repository and while creating the repository, you can pass the property sets data as mentioned [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Configuration+JSON).

Comment: Hi Gajapathi Kimidi, thank you for your reaction , but as I wrote in my request above, I always create my repositories from User Interface artifactory,because artifactory runs on a remote server but here I just need to automate my property set ,so that the "intern" property set is automatically added to each new repository ,that I created . I also ready this [link]https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Property+Sets ,but I dont find nothing

Comment: There is no option to automatically apply the property sets to the newly created repositories from UI. We need to apply them while we create the repository. The option what is available is, the properties can be applied to all the artifacts under a repository automatically if we set a property on repeated mode. 

Also, when you have access to UI, you should be able to create the repositories from REST API too. You may use same template for every new repository creation.

Comment: How to set a property on repeated mode ?

Comment: Added another answer with image. (since image is not allowed in comments)

Comment: It maybe not possible to set property using Groovy?

Comment: It is not possbile to add a plugins on artifactory , who automatically add the property set to new repository ?

Answer (score 0):

Through API you can try the below command:
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ***token*** put https://***artifactoryurl***/artifactory/api/storage/***repository***/***Buildname***/***versionDeployed***?properties=**Builtby**=**intern**&recursive=1

Note:
recursive = 0 (Non-recursive)
recursive = 1 (recursive property apply)